# Set scale for labels

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, scale

I have multiple shapefiles with different geometry and I am trying to add a label of layers.

For creating a map I am using GeoServer and OpenLayers.

Requirement is layer are visible on a max zoom level but labels are visible on min zoom level for same shapefile.

Ex : Layer gets visible at 1:6,00,000 but labels gets visible at 1:5000 for the same shapefile.

Please if anyone know the answer reply me as soon as possible.